# scheduler in mysql to run between hours

Tags: mysql, sql, scheduled-tasks

I want to create a scheduled mysql query every minute between the hours of 9AM and 11PM.

The syntax I am familiar with is

```
    DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    EVENT `record_total_points`
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR STARTS concat(date(now()), ' ', '09:00:00')
    DO BEGIN
            END */$$
                DELIMITER ;
```

How can I restrict it to run between the hours mentioned above?

Answer (score 2):

Just try to add this ([Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/ja/create-event.html))

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    EVENT `record_total_points`
EVERY 1 minute STARTS  DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) ,  "%m-%d-%y 09:00:00" ) ENDS  DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) ,  "%m-%d-%y 23:00:00" )
DO BEGIN
            END */$$
                DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just add an ENDS statement `ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 HOUR STARTS concat(date(now()), ' ', '09:00:00') ENDS concat(date(now()), ' ', '011:01:00')` ?